# cannot read property setdefaults of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I want that What's wrong with this?

This error has occurred.

"cannot read property 'setdefaults' of undefined datepicker"

I don't know why this errer`enter code here`

I did search this error but every say same this answer
'That jquery should not be declared twice.'
So I found the place where it was declared twice, but i don't found

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xthml">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<!--달력 이벤트-->
<script>
    
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        prevText: '이전 달',
        nextText: '다음 달',
        monthNames: ['1월', '2월', '3월', '4월', '5월', '6월', '7월', '8월', '9월', '10월', '11월', '12월'],
        monthNamesShort: ['1월', '2월', '3월', '4월', '5월', '6월', '7월', '8월', '9월', '10월', '11월', '12월'],
        dayNames: ['일', '월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토'],
        dayNamesShort: ['일', '월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토'],
        dayNamesMin: ['일', '월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토'],
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        yearSuffix: '년',
        showOn: 'both', 
        buttonImage: '../css/img/calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true
     });

    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $("#chk_dt").datepicker();
    });

 function equip_chg(){
    var equip_cd_nm = $('#equip_no > option:selected').attr("value2");
    
    $('#equip_cd_nm').val(equip_cd_nm);
 }

</script>

<body>
  <th>date</th>
                            <td><input type="text" class="calendar" id="chk_dt" name="chk_dt" value=""></td>

 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

             equip_chg()
            
            var chk_dt = document.getElementById("chk_dt").value;
            
            $('#inspector').val("<%=user_nm%>");

            //console.log("");
            //오늘날짜
            var date = new Date(); 
            var year = date.getFullYear(); 
            var month = date.getMonth()+1; 
            var day = date.getDate(); 
            // 한자리수일 경우 0을 채워준다. 
            if(month < 10){ 
            month = "0" + month; 
            } 
            if(day < 10){ 
            day = "0" + day; 
            } 
            var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day

            if(chk_dt == ""){

                $('#chk_dt').val(today);  
            }else{

                $('#chk_dt').val(chk_dt);
            }


        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Share the code in which you get that error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not have the correct scrpts in your header.
datepicker is not part of the jquery library but of jquery ui and that js file wasn't included. I fixed in the sample below BUT you still need to include all required images in your site to make it look good

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xthml">

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<!--달력 이벤트-->
<script>
    
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        prevText: '이전 달',
        nextText: '다음 달',
        monthNames: ['1월', '2월', '3월', '4월', '5월', '6월', '7월', '8월', '9월', '10월', '11월', '12월'],
        monthNamesShort: ['1월', '2월', '3월', '4월', '5월', '6월', '7월', '8월', '9월', '10월', '11월', '12월'],
        dayNames: ['일', '월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토'],
        dayNamesShort: ['일', '월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토'],
        dayNamesMin: ['일', '월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토'],
        showMonthAfterYear: true,
        yearSuffix: '년',
        showOn: 'both', 
        buttonImage: '../css/img/calendar.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true
     });

    $(document).ready(function() {    
        $("#chk_dt").datepicker();
    });

 function equip_chg(){
    var equip_cd_nm = $('#equip_no > option:selected').attr("value2");
    
    $('#equip_cd_nm').val(equip_cd_nm);
 }

</script>

<body>
  <th>date</th>
                            <td><input type="text" class="calendar" id="chk_dt" name="chk_dt" value=""></td>

 <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {

             equip_chg()
            
            var chk_dt = document.getElementById("chk_dt").value;
            
            $('#inspector').val("<%=user_nm%>");

            //console.log("");
            //오늘날짜
            var date = new Date(); 
            var year = date.getFullYear(); 
            var month = date.getMonth()+1; 
            var day = date.getDate(); 
            // 한자리수일 경우 0을 채워준다. 
            if(month < 10){ 
            month = "0" + month; 
            } 
            if(day < 10){ 
            day = "0" + day; 
            } 
            var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day

            if(chk_dt == ""){

                $('#chk_dt').val(today);  
            }else{

                $('#chk_dt').val(chk_dt);
            }


        });
    </script>
</body>
```